# (Closed) C++ & Direct3D 9 - How to draw formatted text? (Like printf etc)

Tags: c++, directx, printf, direct3d

I've recently started some programming in C++ using DirectX. I'm not new to C++ as I've used Allegro & SDL before. So far, I can draw text to the screen. However, now I have a slight problem, where I cannot draw a variable to the screen. Ideally, I want to draw a string + an int value. However I have no idea how to do that. This is a snippet of my code so far:

```
font->DrawTextA(sprite, "Score: ", -1, scoreR, DT_CALCRECT, 0xFFFFFFFF);
font->DrawTextA(sprite, "Score: ", -1, scoreR, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

As you might expect, this would write "Score: " to the screen. I need it to write the 'score' variable after that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use sprintf to write a formatted string to memory and then send that string to DrawTextA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sprintf to format a string into a memory string, and then print it using DrawText

Example: (not tested)

```
char formatted_string[100];
sprintf(formatted_string, "Score: %d", score);
font->DrawTextA(sprite, formatted_string, -1, scoreR, DT_CALCRECT, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Obviously this is just illustrative, as this could be much more polished.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. For some reason when I tried this before it didn't, it might have been because I was using a char pointer instead of a char array.

Comment: For sure. sprintf requires an allocated string to write to. Best luck for you!